# Raphael.js maintaining transform while during an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael, transform

been searching high and low and I can't seem to find an answer. I'm working with Raphael.js and I'm trying to make an element, let's say a  rotate while I hover over it. The problem is, if I've used the transform Raphael function to translate, rotate or scale the element, all those attributes vanish.
Here's what I have so far:

```
<body>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var paper = Raphael(100, 100, $(document).height(), $(document).width());
            var gear1 = paper.path("M57.585,29.421 c-0.52-5.537,6.43-0.361,5.004-5.732 c-1.432-5.379-4.9,2.561-7.197-2.509 c-2.293-5.063,5.971-2.442,2.873-7.062 c-3.092-4.616-3.807,4.025-7.631-0.023 c-3.811-4.046,4.871-4.238,0.438-7.605c-4.428-3.363-2.303,5.041-7.225,2.453c-4.928-2.592,3.225-5.598-2.068-7.344 c-5.277-1.746-0.533,5.511-6.027,4.659c-5.5-0.854,1.217-6.326-4.348-6.257 c-5.564,0.061,1.293,5.379-4.186,6.354 c-5.475,0.98-0.895-6.373-6.137-4.511 c-5.242,1.869,2.955,4.676-1.902,7.373c-4.867,2.704-2.922-5.739-7.277-2.272 c-4.348,3.469,4.322,3.452,0.604,7.584 c-3.721,4.137-4.633-4.477-7.615,0.216 c-2.992,4.687,5.203,1.859,3.025,6.982 c-2.176,5.116-5.836-2.733-7.137,2.675 c-1.303,5.404,5.537,0.076,5.146,5.619 c-0.395,5.547-6.416-0.695-5.893,4.838 c0.523,5.531,5.266-1.727,6.693,3.648s-6.295,1.429-3.996,6.496 c2.289,5.062,4.42-3.341,7.516,1.275 c3.096,4.619-5.488,3.387-1.67,7.433 c3.816,4.05,3.088-4.59,7.516-1.226 c4.428,3.363-4.086,4.98,0.834,7.571 c4.926,2.595,1.432-5.339,6.715-3.595 c5.285,1.746-2.24,6.03,3.26,6.885 c5.492,0.85-0.391-5.52,5.17-5.583 c5.566-0.066-0.158,6.448,5.316,5.468 c5.477-0.975-2.148-5.106,3.094-6.973 c5.242-1.865,1.932,6.15,6.793,3.443 c4.861-2.704-3.691-4.115,0.656-7.586 c4.355-3.465,3.832,5.187,7.553,1.051 c3.721-4.139-4.838-2.697-1.85-7.383 c2.99-4.691,5.309,3.652,7.486-1.461 c2.174-5.12-5.447-0.988-4.146-6.396 c1.307-5.404,6.211,1.74,6.605-3.804 C63.974,28.576,58.108,34.958,57.585,29.421 z M49.186,19.025 l-12.812,7.396 c-0.666-0.577-1.438-1.034-2.289-1.325 v-14.56 C40.254,11.125,45.648,14.333,49.186,19.025 z M31.798,35.296 c-1.979,0-3.582-1.609-3.582-3.585 c0-1.981,1.604-3.585,3.582-3.585 v-0.004c1.979,0,3.586,1.607,3.586,3.589 C35.384,33.687,33.776,35.296,31.798,35.296 z M29.501,10.594 v14.509 c-0.842,0.299-1.617,0.736-2.275,1.312l-12.487-7.204 C18.179,14.538,23.449,11.306,29.501,10.594 z M24.919,33.026l-12.66,7.318 c-1.103-2.587-1.715-5.431-1.715-8.418 c0-3.122,0.681-6.08,1.879-8.758 l12.496,7.223 c-0.084,0.424-0.117,0.869-0.117,1.319 S24.835,32.603,24.919,33.026 z M14.512,44.34 l12.714-7.331 c0.658,0.567,1.434,1.012,2.275,1.307 v14.946 C23.317,52.534,17.945,49.179,14.512,44.34 z M34.085,53.318 V38.329 c0.852-0.299,1.623-0.76,2.289-1.336 l13.038,7.533 C45.883,49.385,40.387,52.719,34.085,53.318 z M51.705,40.555 l-13.028-7.528 c0.086-0.424,0.119-0.865,0.119-1.315 s-0.033-0.896-0.119-1.319l12.864-7.433 c1.26,2.732,1.981,5.764,1.981,8.968 C53.522,34.997,52.867,37.912,51.705,40.555 z").attr({stroke:'#000',fill:'#000'});
            gear1.transform("t100,200 s0.5");
            gear1.node.id = "gear1";
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

and the CSS is as follows:

```
/*Rotation functionality for Gear1*/
#gear1{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.5s;
    transition-duration: 1.5s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;

    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}  

#gear1:hover  
{
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -moz-animation-name: rotate; 
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
} 

/*Rotation keyframes*/
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

So, to reiterate. I've looked everywhere, the rotation onhover aspect works fine, the problem is "What happens to my *gear1.transform(...);*? Why is it just disappearing?"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could add a fiddle? I would suggest to try Element.hover() in combination with Element.animate().

Comment: I'm guessing the new animation is overriding the old, so one way or another you probably need to include the original transformation as part of the animation (you can do relative transformations in Raphael, but not sure that CSS can), so Rodrigos suggestion is certainly one route that should work. just thinking, another solution could be to transform a parent element via css, problem is Raphael doesn't support group elements as default, so Snap or a group plugin maybe another route ?